# How to deal async scripts in slow network?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I have a webpage where I had to work with [Zingchart](https://www.zingchart.com/). I had to call the Zingchart library inside the **head tag** and the scripts where I have written some code to draw charts are before **body**. For passing [web.dev](http://web.dev/) performance metrics, I have added async to the Zingchart library:

```
<html>
 <head>
  ... 
  <script async src="https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  ... 
 </head>
 <body>
  ... 
  ... 
  <script src="chartDrawing.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now, this works perfect in a high-speed network. But when the bandwidth is lower then the Zingchart library takes some time to load. But the **chartDrawing.js** executes somehow as it is not async.

I want to know, what will be the perfect way to deal with such situation?

Comment: why don't you set `async` or `defer` on `<script src="chartDrawing.js"></script>` too?